# Word 2007 does not update when printing

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, updates

I used the "update fields when printing" option for years; it is a useful feature.

Unfortunately, the update stopped working a few years ago. Our IT guys say it's because of one of the service packs, but that seems odd, especially when I see people asking how to stop the automatic update.

Comment: What exactly does that option do? And are you sure that "people" are not referring to _windows_ automatic update?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. At this point you've not actually asked a question. To improve chances of getting useful answers and avoid this being closed, please [edit] your post with what have you already tried and what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure the fields that are not updating are not just locked?